# JUnit4 plug-in and build path for junit.jar in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, junit4

I've got Eclipse (Helios) installed along with the JUnit3, JUnit4 and Java Development Tools plug-ins for some Android development.

I've created some unit tests but the only way they run (without throwing a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` for `org.junit.Test`) is if I add an External JAR to the test project build path for `junit.jar` from the normal JUnit install I have.

Why isn't Eclipse able to reference the `junit.jar` from the JUnit4 plugin which I can see when I expand the library in Package Explorer? In fact I can remove the JUnit4 Library from the test project leaving just the External JAR and the tests run fine.

I tried adding the path to the plug-in folder to my CLASSPATH system environment variable as I had to setting up JUnit but this made no difference. The plugin path is created as a JUNIT_HOME Classpath Variable in Eclipse but this is labeled as deprecated.

Do I even need the JUnit3 and JUnit4 plugins as these must have come with the distro I used?

Answer (score 2):

In any new project, the sure way I add the required `Junit deps` (with the exception of declaring them in maven) is through creating the test using the in-built `Junit test` shortcut.

Go to New > `Junit Test Case`. If the right deps are not on the project classpath, eclipse will pull them in automatically.